# Sheet of paper in millimeters

Tags: python

I been asked to write a program that displays the dimensions of a letter-size (8.5 x 11 inches) sheet of paper in millimetres. There are 25.4 millimetres per inch. I need to use constants and comments in my program. This is what I come up with:

```
#This is a program that displays dimensions of a letter-size
#sheet of paper in millimeters.
# Conversion from inches to millimeters.
# w = 8.5 inches * 25.4mm/inch = 215.9 mm
# h = 11 inches *25.4mm/inch = 279.4 mm
# Define constants
WIDTH_IN_MILLIMETERS = 215.9
HEIGHT_IN_MILLIMETERS = 279.4

#Compute and print dimmensions of a letter-size sheet of paper in millimeters.
dimLetterSize = WIDTH_IN_MILLIMETERS * HEIGHT_IN_MILLIMETERS

print("The dimentions of a letter-size sheet of paper in millimeters: %6d" % dimLetterSize)
```

Comment: So... what's your question? Here's a clue - the only constant in your code should be `25.4`, and nowhere are you asked to calculate the *area* of the sheet.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I was not asked to calculate area.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my answer to your assignment. I hope you get full marks.

```
# This is a program that displays dimensions of a letter-size
# sheet of paper in millimeters.

WIDTH = 8.5
HEIGHT = 11

MILLIMETERS_IN_INCHES = 25.4

print("The dimentions of a letter-size sheet of paper in millimeters is : {} x {}", WIDTH * MILLIMETERS_IN_INCHES, HEIGHT * MILLIMETERS_IN_INCHES)
```

Comment: That was a quick respond. Thanks!