# I been asked to write a program that prompts the user for a measurement in meters and then converts it in to miles, feet and inches

Tags: python

```
# Program to convert meters into miles

# Prompts input from the user
meters = float(input("How many meters?: "))

# Convert factor

conv_fac = 0.000621371

# calculate miles

miles = meters * conv_fac
print("%0.3f meters is equal to %0.3f miles"  %(meters, miles))
```

So my question is how proceed to continue to convert to feet and inches if this is correct to convert to miles. 
Do I need to convert those miles that I entered to feet?

Comment: If I understand well, your question is "XX meters => AA miles and BB feet and CC inches" vs. "XX meters => DD miles or EE feet or FF inches"? If so you should ask the one asking you for the program..

Comment: Your code looks reasonable; just add a new conversion factor.

Comment: If you want a package that does unit conversions for you, check out [quantities](http://pythonhosted.org//quantities/user/tutorial.html) ([PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quantities))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sheet of paper in millimeters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379493/sheet-of-paper-in-millimeters)

Comment: I am trying to figure out whether I was been asked to convert meters to miles than miles to feet and feet to inches.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 1 mile = 5280 feet.

So: `feet = miles * 5280`

1 foot = 12 inches.

So: `inches = feet * 12`

Comment: Can I write this way my program?                             # Program to convert miles into feet

# Prompts input from the user
miles = float(input("How many miles?: "))

# Convert factor

conv_fac = 5280

# calculate miles

feet = miles * conv_fac
print("%0.3f miles is equal to %0.3f feet"  %(miles, feet))
# Program to convert feet into inches

# Prompts input from the user
feet = float(input("How many feet?: "))

# Convert factor

conv_fac = 12

# calculate miles

inch = feet * conv_fac
print("%0.3f feet is equal to %0.3f inches"  %(feet, inches))